# center Bootstrap content with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the contents of the Bootstrap inspired grid (Fiddle below) to center when the browser width is maximized.  I would like to see the 4 and 5 blocks center in their screen.  What CSS could I apply to make this happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Scaffolding · Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="row show-grid">
                <div class="span4">
                    4</div>
                <div class="span5">
                    5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/m4DqZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `body` tag the class `container`. This should center the `div` with the class `row`.

```
<body class="container">
```